# MySQL SELECT DateTime (Staff Check-In Report)

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a setup a Staff Check-in Record with the following table:

```
Table: ChkIn
ciid | stfid | cidt
-----------------------------------
1    | 1     | 2015-03-07 09:28:35
2    | 18    | 2015-03-07 09:31:30
3    | 68    | 2015-03-07 09:33:02

           (omitted ...)

361  | 968   | 2015-03-11 09:34:15
362  | 18    | 2015-03-11 09:35:01
363  | 322   | 2015-03-11 09:37:38
364  | 169   | 2015-03-11 09:41:23
365  | 224   | 2015-03-11 09:48:04
```

ci = Check In
stf = Staff
dt = DateTime

And now I want to generate a report (or you can say its a list) for the records came to office in the morning (between 09:30:00 to 11:59:59), early arrived (on or before 09:29:59) and which records were checked-in in the afternoon (on or after 12:00:00).

I am having a problem that the data is inaccurate (I know why it is inaccurate but I don't know how to solve them). For example, I want the date range from 1 Jan 2014 to 31 Mar 2015 and they came on time:

```
SELECT c.stfid, c.cidt, s.name
FROM ChkIn c, Staff s
WHERE c.stfid = s.stfid
  AND YEAR(c.cidt) >= '2014'
  AND YEAR(c.cidt) <= '2015'
  AND MONTH(c.cidt) >= '1'
 AND MONTH(c.cidt) <= '3' 
 AND HOUR(c.cidt) >= '9' 
 AND HOUR(c.cidt) <= '11'
AND MINUTE(c.cidt) >= '30'
AND MINUTE(c.cidt) <= '59'
```

For experts in SQL, you may already know the problem:
1. Record in Apr 2014 to Dec 2014 => EXCLUDED
2. Any hour in 0 - 30 Minute => EXCLUDED

So ... how to solve?
I don't want to break apart the DateTime into 2 columns. But if you can provide a filter for PHP code, it is still OK for me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you need record 1 jan 2014 to 31 mar 2015 excluded apr 2014 up to dec 2014? date range specific or not just let me clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the DATE and TIME parts of a DATETIME column using the DATE() and TIME() functions, you could then do a comparison on that part only.

For example you can do like;

```
WHERE
 (DATE(cidt) BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2015-03-01')
 AND
 (TIME(cidt) BETWEEN '09:30:00' AND '11:59:59')
```

See:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff

Comment: Thank you for your solution and MySQL for this amazing function. Just worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

try this query at your system

```
SELECT temp.*  FROM
(
 SELECT 
  c.stfid,
  c.cidt,
  s.name 
FROM
  ChkIn c,
  Staff s 
WHERE c.stfid = s.stfid 
 c.cidt BETWEEN '2014-01-01 00:00:00'
  AND  '2014-12-31 23:59:59' 
 ) AS temp WHERE  MONTH(temp.cidt) >0 AND  MONTH(temp.cidt)< 4
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select * from ChkIn c, Staff s WHERE c.stfid = s.stfid
where YEAR(c.cidt) <= 2015
and (case when YEAR(c.cidt) = 2014 then month(c.cidt) <= 3 else month(c.cidt) = month(c.cidt) end )
and HOUR(c.cidt) >= 9 AND HOUR(c.cidt) <= 11
AND MINUTE(c.cidt) >= 30 AND MINUTE(c.cidt) <= 59;
```